# searching for a foreign object via manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, search, manytomanyfield

Hay i have a model

```
def Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

def User(models.Model):
```

and i can add "users" to the "friend" model by using

```
friend = Friends.objects.get(pk=1)
user = User.objects.get(pk=2)
friend.add(user)
```

However, how can i check to see if the Friend object has a certain User? And if it does remove that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to delete the user if it's present, but don't actually care whether it exists or not, you can just do this:

```
friend.users.filter(pk=user.pk).delete()
```

Comment: No, as I said, it doesn't care. `filter` will return an empty QuerySet, and `delete` will be a no-op.